# File upload with Polymer & material design

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm wanting to make a paper/material design version of the `<input type="file">`, can anybody suggest anything for my code below?

```
<paper-input type="text" id="fileName" placeholder="File" readonly></paper-input>
<paper-button id="changePicture" class="changePicture">Upload Picture</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [paper-input-container](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container) to get the same behavior and material design as paper-input.

If you are brave enough to explore others code you can take a look at [Vaadin-upload](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/vaadin/vaadin-upload) element :)

Comment: I'd seen Vaadin before but wasn't sure. I've gone for my own hodge-podge solution at this point haha

Answer (score 0):

Find on webcomponents.org, https://www.webcomponents.org/search/upload

e.g. http://file-input.raynicholus.com/components/file-input/demo.html